# Facebook Connect: Load New Page After Login

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, facebook, onload

I'm looking to replicate the flow of airbnb's login system, on my website:

1) User logs in via facebook: https://www.airbnb.com/login
2) Once user is authenticated, a new page loads: http://www.airbnb.com/home/dashboard

I imagine this has something to do with the onload attribute of the fb:login-button, but I'm too much of a noob to get it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once they are logged, in just run the following js:

```
window.location = "http://www.airbnb.com/home/dashboard";
```